# Showing that a rotation is (not) a parametric surface - how?

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $c:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3$ be a curve with $c(r)=\pmatrix{r ,0 ,e^r}$ let $S$ be the surface of revolution, which is caused by the rotation of $c(r)$ around the $x_3$-axis.

I shall show that $S$ is not a parametric surface.

My ideas so far:

1) As $x_2=0$ we are looking at the $x_1x_3$-plane.

2) The rotation should be a cone.

3) For $r=0$ is $c(0)= (0;0;1)$ a critical point

4) So $S\setminus\{(0,0,1)\}$ should be a parametric surface

My problem is that I don't know how to describe $S$ and that I have problems with the defintion of parametric surface.

Would it be :

$\pmatrix{cos &-sin &0 \\ sin & cos & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1}\pmatrix{r\\0\\e^r}=\pmatrix{r\cdot cos(\phi) \\r \cdot sin(\phi)\\e^r} $

$S=f(\Bbb R^2)=\{(r\cdot cos(\phi), r \cdot sin(\phi),e^r)\in\Bbb R^3|r,\phi\in\Bbb R\}$ ?

Any help/hint would be great !